# How can I get a single column out of a spark dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark

I would like to take a single column out of my spark dataframe.

[image: Here is the dataframe]

And I would like to put the latitude in a variable, and the longitude.
When I do this;

[image: Latitude]

I only get the column name.

Comment: if i understand well, you want to extract the data from the spark dataframe to process them with python, don't you ? I do not know what you want to do after but you should keep working with the spark dataframe.

Comment: Yes correct, I want to place different lats&long on a map but right now I still fail to do so. Pure with spark, not with pandas

Answer (score 0):

Well all you need to do is :

```
Lats = [row[0] for row in df.select('latitude').collect()]
print(Lats)
```

Comment: Yep exactly, and how do I filter out the column name, so that it only shows the values ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question, edited the answer accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

The best or corrected way to select any column would be to use **`col()`** function in order to let spark know that it's not a string and also this will not be dependent on that Dataframe (i.e in case the dataframe is deleted df.select("name") might give issue)

```
df = df.select(F.col("some_column_name")
```

Likewise, same for filter operation , use **`lit`** to make spark understand it is string -

```
df  =  df.filter(F.col("some_column_name") == F.lit("a_string"))
```